# "sh: logger: command not found" if slurm script submitted via os.system in Python

Tags: python, sh, slurm

I am submitting jobs to a cluster that is managed with SLURM. I have a python script that automates my job submission since I am doing hyperparameter tuning.

In my python script, I run

```
os.system('sbatch ' + fname)
```

where `fname` is a text file containing all the settings for the job to be submitted. I used this set-up for a previous cluster I was working on and it worked fine.

Now I'm trying the same set-up on a different cluster and my script doesn't work. I get the complaint: sh: sbatch: command not found. I fixed this by using

```
os.system('/usr/local/slurm/bin/sbatch ' + fname)
```

instead. The script now works and is now able to submit to jobs.

However, when I look at the output file, the first line says

> sh: logger: command not found

The job executed fine though. It was a simple `print("Hello world")` just for testing.

I find this strange since this now occurs after submitting the job to Slurm. If I just do sbatch fname on the terminal, I don't get this complaint printed on the log file.

I'm not sure how to resolve this. I'm concerned that I'll run into problems with other commands if the code gets more complicated.

If it  makes a difference, the python script has the virtual shebang `#!/usr/bin/python -u` at the start of the file.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the _bash_ tag, since there is no bash involved in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `echo $PATH` on the command-line. Its a list of pathnames separated by colon (`:`). In Python, before calling `os.system(...)`, set `os.environ['PATH']` to something which contains the programs `sbatch`, `logger` etc. Don't remove old entries either.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Just for my understanding: why does one still need to set os.environ['PATH']? Why doesn't os.system work exactly as if I ran the command on the command line?

Comment: os.system runs /bin/sh in a subprocess, which runs the specified command. PATH remains unchanged here unless /bin/sh is configured to change it at noninteractive startup (very very rare). In your case, PATH was changed before os.system was called. You may want to add lots of `import os; print(os.environ['PATH'])` lines to your Python program to figure out where. Maybe it was changed before the 1st line of your Python code.

Comment: It does, but the environment in which it runs is different. Jobs you submit via `sbatch` do not run your `.bashrc` etc.